# How to use TensorFlow tf.data.experimental.group_by_reducer

Tags: tensorflow, mapreduce

I have a 2D matrix which i want to aggregate based on a columns value. Effectively i want to do a map reduce on my data.

I notice there is a function called tf.data.experimental.group_by_reducer which looks promising but there are no examples at all on how to use it or the functions you declare.

Does anybody have an example on how to use this function to aggregate based on a column or, if this is not the most appropriate function then what would be another mechanism to achieve my result?

Also i am reading my dataset in batches, so the reduce would be done on each batch. I am assuming the only way to apply a reduce across the entire dataset in this method is to then do a reduce on the reductions from each batch?